# Make access to unsigned char thread-safe (atomic)

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety

I am well aware that similar questions have been asked before and I'm also aware, that the operation is most likely not atomic at all, but I'm still asking out of idle curiosity and in hope that there's some way to MAKE it atomic.

The situation: Inside a `struct`, there's an unsigned char variable called `Busy`. (It can be moved out of there and stand on its own though).

This variable `Busy` is modified by two concurrent threads, one who sets bits on scheduling and one who clears them upon completion of the scheduled action.

Right now, the scheduling looks like this:

```
while(SEC.Busy&(1 << SEC.ReqID))
    if(++SEC.ReqID == 5) SEC.ReqID = 0;
sQuery.cData[2] = SEC.ReqID;
```

while the clearing of the bitmaks looks like this:

```
SEC.Busy &= ~(1 << sQuery->cData[2]);
```

cData[2] basically carries the information about which slot is used over the network and comes back via a callback in another thread.

Now the question: How can I make sure that SEC.Busy (which is the only variable in this troubled situation) doesn't get torn apart by two threads trying to alter it at the same time without using a mutex, critical section or anything of the likes if possible?

I've also tried assigning the content of SEC.Busy to a local variable, alter that and then write the variable back, but unfortunately this operation also doesn't seem atomic.

I'm using Borland C++ Builder 6 at the moment, though a GCC solution would also be just fine.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Setting bits on a single char sounds *terrible*. The bane of concurrency is sharing, and here you're needlessly enforcing a ton of pointless sharing. If you can spare the memory, make each flag occupy the size of a word, or better yet a whole cache line (64 bytes).

Comment: @KerrekSB So you're suggesting that I'm using an array of boolean characters instead of one character, correct?

Comment: I'm probably suggesting you're using a very sparse array that's padded so that each element starts on a 64-byte boundary. That way, no single flag check collides with any different flag check. (That doesn't have anything to do with your question, but it's a fairly important consideration.)

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't think what you are suggesting will work.  Look at the clearing operation.  It simultaneously clears all but one of the bits.  This presumably also needs to be done atomically, and thus inside a single atomic variable.  Synchronization variables _need_ to be shared.

Comment: @WanderingLogic: Perhaps. If atomic clearing is needed, it might be better to use a mutex (and then it's OK to use a single byte to store the state). Which design is best depends on the access profile.

Comment: @WanderingLogic Actually I'm clearing only one bit by logically anding it with the inverted bitmask of the bit I want to clear. So if I want to clear Bit 4, it'd `AND` it with `1111 0111`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++03 (nor C99) does not say anything about atomicity at all. *Assignment* is atomic (= everybody sees either the old or the new value) on most platforms, but because it is not synchronized (= anybody may see the old value after they saw new value for other updates) on any, it is useless anyway. Any other operation like increment, set bit and such is likely not even atomic.

C++11 defines [`std::atomic` template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), which ensures both atomicity and synchronization, so you need to use it. Boost provides compatible implementation for most C++03 compilers and gcc [has had built-in support since 4.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/_005f_005fsync-Builtins.html), which is being replaced by [more advanced support needed by C++11 in gcc 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.3/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html)

Windows API had ["Interlocked operations"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) since long ago. Unix alternative required assembly (which several libraries provided) before introduction of the gcc `__sync` function.

Comment: I beg your forgiveness, but does that mean, unless my compiler can perform C++11 (which BCB 6 cannot do as far as I'm aware), I'm stuck? Or does that mean I'm 'good' nonetheless, because the operation is atomic nonetheless, despite it appearing as multiple operations when looking at assembler? Besides, even if there's a race condition, it doesn't hurt me in this case, because even if a slot is read as 'occupied' while it's being freed, it will simply be used in the next go. Will that work?

Comment: No, you're not stuck. You could simply use a compiler that's a bit more up to date. BCB6 is from 2002, wich was even before C++03 standard came out. Now we have 2013, C++11 is out with the first compilers being feature complete, and C++14 community draft is already out.

Comment: @ATaylor: BCB 6 is windows-specific. So just use the `Interlocked*` functions.

Comment: @ArneMertz Heh, yeah I could do that, if the project would allow it. (It's been around for about as long and we never managed to migrate yet.) But I'll suggest it to my superior.

Comment: @JanHudec Aren't the Interlocked functions only available for .NET applications? I'm still looking at the page.

Comment: @ATaylor: No, they are availble natively since ages. I first linked wrong reference, than replaced. Please take the current link.

Answer (score 1):

There are **three** potential problems when accessing shared data from multiple threads. First, you might get a thread switch in the middle of a memory access that requires more than one bus cycle; this is called "tearing". Second, each processor has its own memory cache, and writing data to one cache does not automatically write to other caches, so a different thread can see stale data. Third, the compiler can move instructions around, so that another processor might see a later store to one variable without seeing a preceding store to another one.

Using a variable of type `unsigned char` almost certainly removes the first one, but it doesn't have any effect on the other two.

To avoid all three problems, use `atomic<unsigned char>` from C++11 or whatever synchronizing techniques your compiler and OS provide.